# How to make GNU screen auto start when login?

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-screen

I have several linux servers to work on every day, and I have a GNU screen session on each of them to preserve work progress.

The question is I am so tired of issue `screen -Rd work` every time I login, is there anyways to get rid of that? Or any workarounds?

---

Reading @Sami's answer, I did some search on the `$STY` shell variable and [found](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_20.html) this:

> STY: Alternate socket name. If screen is invoked, and the environment variable STY is set, then it creates only a window in the running screen session rather than starting a new session.

So I think the key is the `$STY` variable, we may append it to either .bashrc or .profile, as long as it gets executed upon login. Thanks @Sami

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on your shell. In case you use any of Bourne Shell derivatives (namely Bash) or Bourne Shell itself, put appropriate commands in `~/.profile`:

```
[ -z "$STY" ] && screen -Rd "work"
```

This will only start a screen session in case you're not already running inside a screen session (screen sets environment variable STY).

In case you're not using Bash or compatible, use the proper shell initialization file with a similar test.

Comment: Great, it works. Thank you. I do use bash I tried to add something like that in .bashrc but failed. Should have added that to .profile.

Comment: The `~/.bashrc` is only consulted for login shells, so for example xterm sessions might not be login shells. I usually just symlink `~/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile` but you might want to keep things separated.

Comment: not working if you use "su - username", STY variable is empty.